# How to set session variable in header file in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am having problem to get session variable in header file. In my controller i have this code for login.

```
public function login(Request $request)
  {
    $inputs = $request->only('email', 'password');
//dd($request->input('email'));
$rules = array(
    'email' =>'required',
    'password' => 'required'
);
$validator = Validator::make($inputs, $rules);
if ($validator->fails()){
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    return redirect('login')
              ->withErrors($validator)
              ->withInput($request->except('password'));
} else {
    if (auth()->attempt($inputs)) {
       $is_admin = DB::table('users')
                     ->where('email', $request->input('email'))
                     ->first();
       if ($is_admin->is_admin == 1) {
           return redirect('/company_details');
       } elseif ($is_admin->is_admin == 2) {
           return redirect('dashboard');
         } else {
            dd('something wrong');
           }
     } else {
        return redirect('login')->withErrors(['error' => 'Email or password donot match']);
     } 
  } 
 }
```

I have a login form which in which my header file is include, and i have to get session variable in my header file. Like if a user is logged in, username or email should appear in place of login button.

Anyone please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
or 
use Session
```

**Set Session Variable**

```
Session::Flash('message_key', 'Your Message');
return redirect('/yourmsgpage')
```

**Show the session output**

```
@if(Session::has('message_key'))
<div>
{{ Session::get('message_key' }} 
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get user session id

```
Auth::user()->id
```